# If airplanes' highest speed depends directly on the air it is moving through and not the ground,

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, time-travel

If airplanes' highest speed depends directly on the air it is moving through and not the ground, does it mean we can build a time machine if only the air moves near the speed of light?

Answer (score 4):

The downvotes are a bit unfair since you ask a good question. You're really asking about the relativistic addition of velocities i.e. if the plane is moving at 0.9$c$ and the air is moving at 0.9$c$ then is the plane moving at 1.8$c$ relative to the ground?

You probably won't be surprised to find that the answer is no (Einstein was right!) because the simple rule for adding velocities $v = v_1 + v_2$ does not work for velocities near the speed of light. You need to use the [relativistic formula for adding velocities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula).

Comment: Well, It may be a good question. But, we've got enough questions on the relativistic addition of velocities. I think you've seen plenty on the topic :-)

Comment: I was actually asking if we can't build a plane that fast, why don't we make air faster? It would still be in total < c. I know we'd have to obey c in small regions of space. And it's still a "time machine" going to the future without having to surpass c or even be very close to it.

Comment: @LelaDax: oops, sorry. Making the air travel at near $c$ seems considerably harder than making some form of craft travel at near $c$. How would you do it? A big fan?

Answer (score 1):

No. You should add velocities using the relativistic rule, so the velocity of the airplane with respect to ground will be less than the velocity of light.